# Linking multiple map displays in Internet Map Server (IMS)?

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-platform

Has anyone heard of any GIS Internet Map Server (IMS) capability program that will allow multiple displays of data to be geo linked.

For example, when one pans on one view it will automatically relocates the extent on the corresponding linked viewer.

Comment: This is possible in all of the ESRI APIs.
Let me know if these are viable option for you and I will hunt down the samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by IMS, you mean a Web map server like ArcGIS Server or MapServer, GeoServer, etc.

I think that this question is really more about building a client that can do this.  The client would keep everything in sync between the two maps and send requests to the server for map images for each map.

I am sure that you could do this with OpenLayers.  I swear that I had seen an example of this, but did some searching and couldn't find one.

Comment: Here is an example that incorporates OpenLayers.  The purpose here was to demonstrate what two different data sets look like.  This was in response to a recent tragic incident where someone followed their car gps into a reservoir.  The Google data still has the roads that were covered up by water 20 years ago.  The OSM data shows the water.  http://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/?mt0=mapnik&mt1=googlehybrid&lon=-5.09448&lat=38.84867&zoom=14

Answer (score 2):

Here's a half-baked app that I think does what you're describing:  http://swingley.appspot.com/maps/four There are a few browser specific issues but I think it is a decent prototype/proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a colleauge that has done some HTML5 websocket demos that does that [HTML5 WebSocket samples goes live](http://dathor.blogspot.com/2010/07/websocket-samples-goes-live.html) using bingmaps.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously written an API which allows you to do this, in the Map Window there is series of options you can use the pan, you can hen have a single pan in a single windo and write code to referesh the other map frames. The code I wrote was specifically for ArcReader, but applies across the entire ArcGIS Suite